# Enable browsers to "remember" form values when using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, back-button

See: http://friendfeed.com/paul/2b7ddce5/jquery-1-3-breaks-bfcache-because-it-binds

I've got a form in my web app, and if the user submits it and presses the browser BACK button the form values are remembered (e.g. any values the user entered).

Once I add jQuery 1.4.2 to the page (e.g. reference it as a script), then this behaviour changes. From what I've read, this happens because jQuery hooks the onunload event, and this is a signal to browsers that the script is not bfcache-aware, so it turns off bfcache.

**UPDATE:** I looked into this a bit further, and this problem was fixed in jQuery 1.4 it seems.  It looks like the problem was caused by the autocomplete plugin I was using, I'll post a resolution if I find one.

Comment: Looking more into this, it doesn't look like jQuery is the culprit afterall, but instead a jquery-autocomplete plugin I'm using.

Comment: So you solved your own question? Or are you looking for a way around j-autocomplete?

Comment: Solved my own question. I'll delete it.

Comment: Don't delete it.  Write an answer for it so that the next person who has the same problem can see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For my forms I use an on submit handler to save each form elements value in a cookie, and then pre populate the fields with that data (in PHP side) .. This way the for always keeps the info, even if the person closes the window and then goes back to it.. Or gets distracted and clicks on some other page..